# Python pandas function to create new dfs in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I have a df including every match of Premier League 2019/2020 season. I want to make a function which create a new df, including all home matches of one club. Df looks like that.

```
HomeTeam:    AwayTeam:    Winner:
Liverpool    Brighton    Liverpool
Chelsea      Watford     Chelsea
Brighton     Liverpool   Liverpool
```

Function I have made:

```
'''Function to create df of home games of every team  
    c = Club name'''

def team_home_df(c):
    return data[(data['HomeTeam'] == c)]
```

Then to assign it to a variable, I need to do it like that:

```
liverpool_home_df = team_home_df('Liverpool')
```

I would like to ask you, how to make it in a loop, to get every team's df with name standard "Team_home_df"?

I have got all team names in array.

```
teams = []
clubs = data['HomeTeam'].unique()
teams.append(clubs)
#check the list
print(teams)
```

Output

```
[array(['Liverpool', 'WestHam', 'Bournemouth', 'Burnley', 'CrystalPalace',
       'Watford', 'Tottenham', 'Leicester', 'Newcastle', 'ManUnited',
       'Arsenal', 'AstonVilla', 'Brighton', 'Everton', 'Norwich',
       'Southampton', 'ManCity', 'SheffieldUnited', 'Chelsea', 'Wolves'],
      dtype=object)]
```

Comment: I'm a big fan of EPL as well, can you share the data?

Comment: https://www.football-data.co.uk/

Comment: Here you can find a lot of datasets

Comment: you can use `df.groupby("HomeTeam")` to get df for every team.